# How do I hide the domain of a smoke sim?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I can't find a way to hide the domain in a smoke simulation. The simulation is baked but I dont see a way to hide the domain.

Here's what the render looks like

[image]

And this is the physics settings

[image]

Comment: The visibility depends on the materials for the smoke domain.

Answer (score 1):

For a smoke simulation to work you don't want to hide the smoke domain, quite the opposite, you need to show it. The domain **is** where the smoke will be created.

What you probably are missing are the volume scatter and volume absorption shaders that are connected to the volume of the smoke domain. Or the settings for volume scatter are using high values making the domain look like a solid.